Не могу выложить библиотеку Python через Github Actions
Выдаёт ошибку. Вот такую:
Run python -m build
* Creating isolated environment: venv+pip...
* Installing packages in isolated environment:
  - setuptools >= 40.8.0
* Getting build dependencies for sdist...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.7/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 389, in <module>
    main()
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.7/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 373, in main
    json_out["return_val"] = hook(**hook_input["kwargs"])
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.12.7/x64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 317, in get_requires_for_build_sdist
    return hook(config_settings)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/tmp/build-env-h8cidbsa/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 335, in get_requires_for_build_sdist
    return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=[])
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/tmp/build-env-h8cidbsa/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 302, in _get_build_requires
    self.run_setup()
  File "/tmp/build-env-h8cidbsa/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 516, in run_setup
    super().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
  File "/tmp/build-env-h8cidbsa/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 318, in run_setup
    exec(code, locals())
  File "<string>", line 21, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 9, in read
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/runner/work/sgtools/sgtools/README'

ERROR Backend subprocess exited when trying to invoke get_requires_for_build_sdist
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.


"No such file or directory: '/home/runner/work/sgtools/sgtools/README" - добавьте README в репозиторий
